# AS3 - Score when hitTestObject

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In this game I made some cubes fall and you have to avoid them. When you've avoided one, it keeps falling and hits the ground (scoreDetector), so everytime it hits the ground, I get 1 point. The problem is that the animatione of the cube keeps looping (that's what I want) but by doing so the score counter removes the point and keeps adding and removing it everytime the animation of the cube starts.

Code:

```
var time:int;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
var score:int = 0;

score = 0;
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cubeFall);

timer.start();

function cubeFall(t:TimerEvent) {

time++;

if (time == 3) {
    cube_1.play();
} else if (time == 10) {
    cube_2.play();
}

// Add Score

else if (cube_1.hitTestObject(scoreDetector)) {
score++;
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use an array that will contain the hitted elements like so :

```
var time:int;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
var score:int = 0;
var hittedObjects:Array = new Array();
score = 0;
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cubeFall);

timer.start();

function cubeFall(t:TimerEvent) {

time++;

if (time == 3) {
    cube_1.play();
} else if (time == 10) {
    cube_2.play();
}

// Add Score

else if (cube_1.hitTestObject(scoreDetector) && hittedObjects.indexOf(cube_1)>0) {
score++;
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;
hittedObjects.push(cube_1);
}
}
```

Comment: That's a decent approach to the problem, but that syntax looks pretty screwy.

Comment: sorry i forgot the '&&' my mistake

Comment: Also shouldn't it be ==0 not >0 ?

Comment: Arrays start from 0 so if the index is zero then the cube is there and the index is 0

Comment: ah I got mixed up about indexOf. Still looks off to my eyes (maybe <0 instead of >0?) but I need to actually run the code to be sure how the condition works :P

Comment: Thanks for the help Khaled, but it didn't worked anyway. I'll ask my teacher.

Comment: you should do that to all your cube in an enter frame loop

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution Khaled, nice thinking! :) but It is not a matter of arrays.  The hitTest should not be in an else if() statement.  It should be in it's own if() statement.  Secondly, score++; should be the only thing inside the hitTest if() statement.  The scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;
should be outside the if() statement.  Here is what it should look like.

```
var time:int;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
var score:int = 0;

score = 0;
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, cubeFall);

timer.start();

function cubeFall(t:TimerEvent) {

time++;

if (time == 3) {
    cube_1.play();
} else if (time == 10) {
    cube_2.play();
}

// Add Score

if (cube_1.hitTestObject(scoreDetector)) {
score++;
}
scoreCounter.text = "Score:  " + score;
}
```